# How to copy csv contents and paste to Excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, xlwings

I am using python v3 xlwings library to interact with MS Excel. I have a csv file `ToCopy.csv` and would like to copy the entire contents of this cvs file into an Excel file.

```
import xlwings as xw

Book_name = 'C:/Temp/ExcelBook.xlsm'
sheet_name = 'SheetName' #paste into this sheet

wb = xw.Book(Book_name)
sht = wb.sheets[sheet_name]
```

I looked at xlwings documentation but am still at a loss on how to get started. Can someone give me a head-start?

I am open to using other methods which are not based on xlwings library. However, my Excel file is password-protected and I know xlwings can handle password-protected Excel files. I am not sure about other methods.

Comment: Probably duplicate question, check (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684610/python-convert-csv-to-xlsx) to see if this can help.

Comment: @ian0411, Thanks but the solution uses `xlsxwriter` which has problem writing to password-protected Excel files. So, I am not able to use it in my context. Preferably, I am looking for an answer which uses xlwings library.

Comment: @ian0411 It's not a duplicate since the other question is asking how to convert from a csv to xlsx while this question is asking how can I paste the contents of a csv into a sheet contained within an xlsx file. They are two different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the documentation http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html

> Reading/writing values to/from ranges is as easy as:
>
> ```
> >>> sht.range('A1').value = 'Foo 1'
> >>> sht.range('A1').value
> ```
>
> 'Foo 1' There are many convenience features available, e.g. Range expanding:
>
> ```
> >>> sht.range('A1').value = [['Foo 1', 'Foo 2', 'Foo 3'], [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]]
> >>> sht.range('A1').expand().value
> [['Foo 1', 'Foo 2', 'Foo 3'], [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]]
> ```

In the first example, a value is written to location A1.
In the second, value are being written A1, B1, C1  and A2, B2, C2

So you probably want to do something like

```
for row,line in enumerate(inputcsv):
  myrange = 'A'+row
  mydata = line.split(',')
  sht.range(myrange).value = mydata
```

Other options:

1. Excel will import csv directly - import manually
2. VBA Macro in excel to import file,
   trigger via xlwing

Comment: How do you get `inputcsv`? I tried to implement your solution until I got stuck at there.

Comment: I found something useful for inputcsv. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139558/read-csv-then-enumerate

Answer (score 4):

Since you write that you've tried xlsxwriter this may not work, but have you considered openpyxl?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ToCopy.csv', header=None, index_col=None)
wb = load_workbook(filename='C:/Temp/ExcelBook.xlsm')
ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.title = 'ToCopy'

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
    ws.append(r)

wb.save('C:/Temp/ExcelBook.xlsm')
```

Comment: index_col = None is the default value fyi.

Answer (score 2):

Try to open the csv and save as xlsx directly:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('C:\source.csv')  # Connect to an existing file
# wb = xw.Book(r'C:\Users\hhsg\Desktop\target.xlsx')  # On Windows: use raw strings to escape backslashes
wb.save('C:\target.xlsx')
# wb.save(r'C:\target.xlsx')  # On Windows: use raw strings to escape backslashes
```