# Access individual values from a csv file, using their row and column indexes

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, indexing

I have a csv file with 100 rows and 100 columns,as shown. The values are all float type numbers. I am trying to write a loop where it will access each value, compare it with some divisions and sort. What is the code to access value from a particular index?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV5ZT.png)

```
while col<=100:
    row=0
    while row<=100:
        dist=distf.1[row]
        if else loop
        row=row+1
    col=col+1`
```

something that does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use enumerate() function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16139758/19949392

Or pandas library: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html